# When is the best time to call a webservice and parse the response in iOS?

Tags: ios, network-programming

I have a REST webservice call. Is it good to call the service in one of the methods of the app delegate, or do I need to call and parse the data in the respective view controller?

Comment: call it when you need it!!!

Comment: I had some issue in one case... I was pulling the data and parsing it in table view controller. In this case im seeing the data on table after one second or two. But when I pulled the day in app delegate and parsed it in table view controller, I'm able to see the data right away. In either cases I'm using dispatch queues.

Comment: if you do it in app delegate, data loads first, and you present it in table view, if you do it on table view, there will be certain delay in loading the data!!! It all depends on how you call the webservice and how you reload your UI!!! Are you doing this on main thread ?

Comment: You are calling your webservice asynchronous, so while your TableView is loading, your app is performing webservice requests too. It's very good practice that every controller calls their respective web service. Caching locally your requests and data it's a good thing too.

Comment: @mr.t - yes It's on main thread. Also, I'm facing one more issue when I see the data on my cells and when I scroll bottom first and then scroll up... I see the data is getting refreshed even though the data I loaded already on the cell... Do you know why? I am doing asynchronous call on the image in tablecell . Can you help me in this case?

Comment: may be you are calling webservice on cellforRowatindex method

Comment: @caio... How to do caching? Is it good way to cache the objects since it has lot of images that I get from the Json.

Comment: @Mr.T ur correct then which is the best place to call?

Comment: call on view did appear using completion block, when the block finishes, reload your table view with new data

Comment: @user4150758 You can use some local database, like Core Data, Realm or YapDatabase. For Images, I strongly recommend [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage)

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what you need.
Don't forget that your app will sometimes go background - then what?

In my app, I'm connecting to my server in

```
func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication)
```

and disconnecting in

```
func applicationWillResignActive(application: UIApplication)
```

But it really depends on you. You can also call your service from your controller (check that you are not blocking the UI...) in `func viewDidLoad()` if you need it ones, or `func viewDidAppear()` if you need it to be changed every time the view appears.

You can also use observer-reporter pattern, where you register some object to listen for events from notification centre, and when you got the data from you web service, you just post a notification about it. The result will be a function call that will manipulate you view as you wish...

Hope that helps a bit.